# Playstore warning: play-services-safetynet has reported critical issues with version 17.0.0

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-integrity-api

I'm developing a Flutter application which should be released on PlayStore but warning about Api integrity pop out.

Now, I read some articles about and I figured out that I have firebase_auth which implements safety-net but no fix is provided.

[./gradlew app:dependecies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxZTP.png)

Reading other people suggestions I found this

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}
```

which works well but I'm not confident that it is best approach.

Now I will start release verification even if the problem is not resolved, but I would like fix it before June.

Any suggestions? Thank you

My firebase_auth flutter package is 4.4.0